# Make API request with different credentials for each request

Tags: encoding, jmeter, base64

I'm trying to make an HTTP request with different user credentials.
I have a CSV file with 50 rows of passwords and usernames and I want JMeter to read it and convert it to tokens which I intend to use in the HTTP header manager.

I can also just base64 encode all the credentials and load in JMeter but couldn't find a way to encode all the data at once.

Any solutions?

Comment: Show your code. what you have tried

Comment: Grammar. Consider using articles when writing. Also you're not really asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Config Element [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to parse through the csv file, then use the resulted variables in the HTTP header manager.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) as a child of your request
2. Configure it like:

   [image: JMeter HTTP Authorization Manager]

   Replace:

   - `http://example.com` with the base URL of the application you're testing
   - make sure `${username}` and `${password}`
3. There is no need to manually add HTTP Header Manager, JMeter is smart enough to generate proper [`Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) out of username and password combination provided

   [image: JMeter Authorization Basic]

Check out [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for more information on bypassing [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in your JMeter tests